# Loop through a main directory and all subs and copy all new/updated files and folders

Tags: python-3.x, loops, directory, copy, subdirectory

I have code that loops through a directory looking for new/updated files to copy and move to a destination directory. The problem is this only 'searches' 2 sub directories in and stops. Need something that is dynamic and will continue until every sub is searched for new/updated files. Can something be implemented with walk?? Any help appreiciated.

```
source_dir = r"C:\...."
destination_dir = r"C:\....."

# copy changed files and directories
for item in os.listdir(source_dir):
    if not item.endswith('.849C9593-D756-4E56-8D6E-42412F2A707B'):
        s = os.path.join(source_dir, item)
        d = os.path.join(destination_dir, item)
        if os.path.isdir(s):
            if not os.path.exists(d):
                shutil.copytree(s, d)
            else:
                for f in os.listdir(s):
                    print(f)
                    sf = os.path.join(s, f)
                    df = os.path.join(d, f)
                    if os.path.isdir(sf):
                        continue
                    if not os.path.exists(df) or os.stat(sf).st_mtime - os.stat(df).st_mtime > 1:
                        shutil.copy2(sf, df)
        else:
            if not os.path.exists(d) or os.stat(s).st_mtime - os.stat(d).st_mtime > 1:
                shutil.copy2(s, d)
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you intend to do, we need to set a threshold time after which we will check if any directory or file is created or modified. The threshold time can be the last time you checked. We also need a source and destination path to copy the directories and files that were newly created or modified. I think the below code handles the problem:

```
import os
import pathlib
import shutil
from datetime import datetime
import time



# Copy files to new directories
def copy_files_to_dirs(files_zipped):
    
    for file in files_zipped:
        
        # Set the source and destination paths
        src_path = file[0]
        dst_path = file[1]
        
        # Copy the files to destination
        shutil.copy(src_path, dst_path)


# Create a directory
def create_dir(new_dirs):
    
    for new_dir in new_dirs:
        os.makedirs(new_dir, exist_ok=True)


# Set the new paths of filtered dirs and files
def set_new_paths(dir_or_file):
    
    # Convert the path to string
    split_text = str(dir_or_file)
    
    # Remove the old path
    split_text = split_text.split(path)[-1]
    
    # Set the new path
    new_path = destination_folder + split_text
    
    return new_path
    
    
# Check if it is a directory or file
def check_dir_or_file(filtered_list):
    
    dirs = []
    files = []
    
    for path in filtered_list:
    
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            dirs.append(path)
        else:
            files.append(path)

    return dirs, files


# Find the dirs and files created or modified after the threshold_datetime
def filter_dir_and_files_by_time(dirs_and_files_with_time):
    
    filtered_list = [file[0] for file in dirs_and_files_with_time if file[1] > threshold_datetime or file[2] > threshold_datetime]
    
    return filtered_list


# Convert times to datetime object
def convert_time(raw_time):
       
    datetime_object = datetime.fromtimestamp(raw_time)
    
    return datetime_object


# Get the list of directories and files with their creation and modification times
def get_time(dirs_and_files):
    
    # Create an empty list
    dirs_and_files_with_time = []
    
    for dir_and_file in dirs_and_files:
        
        # Get the creation and modification times
        creation_time = os.stat(dir_and_file).st_birthtime
        modification_time = os.path.getmtime(dir_and_file)
        
        # Convert times to datetime object
        creation_datetime = convert_time(creation_time)
        modification_datetime = convert_time(modification_time)

        # Make a tuple and add to the list
        dirs_and_files_with_time.append((dir_and_file, creation_datetime, modification_datetime))
        
    return dirs_and_files_with_time


# Copy the dirs and files that were created or modified
def copy_files():
    
    desktop = pathlib.Path(path)
    
    # Get the list of all dirs and files in the path given
    dirs_and_files = list(desktop.rglob("*"))
    
    # Get the list of directories and files with their creation and modification times
    dirs_and_files_with_time = get_time(dirs_and_files)
    
    # Find the dirs and files created or modified after the threshold_datetime
    filtered_list = filter_dir_and_files_by_time(dirs_and_files_with_time)
    
    # Check if it is a directory or file
    dirs, files = check_dir_or_file(filtered_list)
    
    # Set the new paths of filtered dirs and files
    new_dirs = [set_new_paths(dirn) for dirn in dirs]
    new_files = [set_new_paths(filen) for filen in files]
    
    # Create a directory
    create_dir(new_dirs)
    
    # Convert old file path to string
    str_files = [str(file) for file in files]
    
    # Zip old and new file paths
    files_zipped = list(zip(str_files, new_files))
    
    # Copy files to new directories
    copy_files_to_dirs(files_zipped)
    

# Enter a date and time to check dirs and files that were created or modified after
threshold_datetime = datetime(2022, 9, 3, 12, 55, 55) # 2022-09-03 12:55:55

# Enter the directory path to search for folders and files created or modified
path = "/dir_1/dir_2/dir_3"

# Enter the destination folder path to copy the dirs and files created or modified
destination_folder = "/dir_a/dir_b/dir_c"

copy_files()
```

This code worked on my Mac successfully. However, to get creation times for Windows, you may refer to this [page](https://pynative.com/python-file-creation-modification-datetime/).

To get more information about getting the list of files recursively, check out this [page](https://realpython.com/get-all-files-in-directory-python/).